# Regex / htaccess : Multiple Pages

Tags: regex, .htaccess

**What I want**

---

Imagine 3 feeds in a single page what have unique contents and I would like to have a pagination for each feed, so I can paginate 3 feeds at the same time, and when I change a feed's page that doesn't affects the other feeds currently selected pages.

So when I change feed3 to page 12, feed1 remains on page 2 and feed2 remains on page 3

**Example**

---

**change this :** `test.com/pages/feed1=2/feed2=3/feed3=12`

**into this  :** `test.com/index.php?pages=on&feed1=2&feed2=3&feed3=12`

**Note:** there can be more or less than 3 feeds

**The Problem**

---

The problem is that I can't convert multiple variables if I want to change the whole link.

This is the regex what I have tried

`(\/)+pages+(\/)+([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)+(\:)+([0-9])`

but this gets only `/pages/feed1=2`

But I would like to convert all the feeds with their variables so I can work with them in PHP.

Comment: Can you do 2 substitutions ? instead of one?

Comment: one: replace `pages` with `index.php?pages=on`, second replace `/` with `&`

Comment: yes I was thinking about something like this, but how should I do it in htaccess? :|

Comment: just print result to a file, append or print I don't know what else you have in there

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php , and just do 2 string replacements.

one: replace `pages` with `index.php?pages=on`, second replace `/` with `&`

Comment: but I need to do this in htaccess, where I can't use two replacements, I mean I don't know if its possible :)

Comment: @CIRK print/append to .htaccess

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really know what do you mean :|